# Large amount of data handling in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using react with redux for development.
I have around 20000 rows in database. I need to display list to users on screen, 10 rows at a time. I also have sorting and filters applied to the list.
I can think of 2 options

1. Store only UI state of component in the redux state and bring data for each page using ajax/fetch. This way all sorting and filters are applied on server end and i get only 10 rows to display at a time.
2. Bring all data once to redux state and display 10 records. This way we do not request server for data again, as all sorting and filters are applied within data stored in state

What is better option/practice?

Comment: Usually you don't want to be storing tens of thousands of values on the client side, can often impact negatively on user experience depending on the type of data and so on. What about something like getting 250 results each request and paging through them 10 at a time on the front end. Then if they go beyond that, replace the existing 250 with the next 250 from the database. That way you aren't doing DB requests every page, but also aren't storing the entire table in their browser.

Comment: @skypecakes 10 is just a number for example.we can change it any time

Comment: @Jayce444 thanks, yes i agree, fetching larger data and keeping it in state of component is memory intensive

Comment: As suggested the server side pagination is a good idea